# Run time error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba. On clicking a button in sheet1 should bring related data from sheet2 to sheet1. Below is the code. I get runtime error on clicking the button in sheet1 and the debug stops at line 6. I'm not sure where the error is. Please help.

```
1.Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
2. a = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
3. x = 8

4. For i = 2 To a

5. If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value = "Payments" Then

6. Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(i, "C"), Cells(i, "F")).Copy
7. Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
8. Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(x, "D"), Cells(x, "G")).Select
9. ActiveSheet.Paste
10. x = x + 1
11. End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Range() is scoped to Sheet2, but Cells() by itself refers to the activesheet - if that's not Sheet2 it will error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sht2, sht1, a As Long, x As Long, i As Long

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

a = sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
x = 8

For i = 2 To a

     If sht2.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Payments" Then 
          sht2.Cells(i, "C").Resize(1, 4).Copy sht1.Cells(x, "D")
          x = x + 1
     End If

Next

sht1.Select
sht1.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```